# Multiple Inheritance in Python Confusion

Tags: python, python-3.x, multiple-inheritance, python-class

I have the following piece of code implementing multiple inheritance. I expect the call `super(base2,self).__init__()` to print `--> "Printing from base2".` But the program prints nothing; neither it throws error.

```
class base1:
    def __init__(self):
        print("printing from base1")
    
    def method(self,val):
        print("From method of base1", val)

class base2:
    def __init__(self):
        print("printing from base2")
    
    def method(self,val):
        print("From method of base2", val)
        
class child(base1, base2):
    def __init__(self):
        super(base2,self).__init__()  #is not working as expected
        
        
x = child()
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How does Python's super() work with multiple inheritance?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3277367/how-does-pythons-super-work-with-multiple-inheritance)

Comment: Thanks for looking into this. I actually get the concept of MRO. In my case, I am not quite understanding why it is not printing. At least it should throw error. But it is not.

Answer (score 2):

The call to `super` expects the child class as its first param, not the base class. You should be doing

```py
super(child, self).__init__()
```

However, since python 3.0, you can simply do

```py
super().__init__()
```

But how does this play into multiple inheritence? Well that's extremely well explained in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3277367/how-does-pythons-super-work-with-multiple-inheritance)

Basically, in your case, changing `super` to the appropriate call will yield the `base1` class' `__init__` call. According to the MRO (method resolution order).

What if you wanted to invoke the `__init__` of `base2`? Well you're looking into directly calling `base2.__init__()` in that case, or simply changing the order of inheritance.

```py
class child(base2, base1):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
```

Now this will print the `base2` class' `__init__` method

Comment: Thanks for your reply. If I understand correctly, in super(classname,arg1, arg2..), always the class name needs to be a child class in the inheritance hierarchy. Else it wont work as expected. Am I understanding correct ?

Comment: @user3103957 the `classname` in `super`'s first argument should be the *class who's super will be called*, so `super(foo, self)` will call the superclass of `foo`.